# How to make a Ruby on Rails app to be seen from outside of a virtual machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

I set up on my Vmware an Ubuntu 18.10 Server VM. On this, I set up a Rails 5 app and create DB. Until the moment I run the Rails server all seems working correctly. 
DB create was ok and also PSQL working.
When I run `rails -s -b ip -p 3001` the server starts but when I'm writing in my browser the `ip:3001` on an external machine I get unable to connect. 
I would like to know a solution for this as I would like to see my app running in the browser.

Comment: It won't work in the browser because "ip" is inside the VM, not the host machine. Look into NAT, bridging and port forwarding settings for VMWare. It should be a simple setting to expose the IP and/or port - you need to make your host machine forward requests into the VM.

Comment: @mahemoff I did a bridge connection and I'm able to access the server with ssh key also from outside. That was all set up. The only issues are with the Rails server. I'm missing something and would like to be pointed to some references about it.

Comment: It's the same concept for Rails server - need to use something like NAT to map from host machine to ip:3000 on the VM. I don't know the specifics with VMware though.